# Why are these two char arrays not equal?

Tags: c++, string, file

I have these two char arrays that output the same value on console (DESKTOP-KDOD9T), one is read from a file and the other received via winsock gethostname. Compared, they're not the same though. It says you can't access the program.

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" )

int main()
{
    char word[255];
    std::fstream stream;
    stream.open("Text.txt");
    stream >> word;
    std::cout << word << "\n";

    WSADATA wsa_Data;
    WSAStartup(0x101, &wsa_Data);

    char buffer[255];
    gethostname(buffer, 255);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

    WSACleanup();

    if (word == buffer)
    {
        std::cout << "Welcome!\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << ".";
                Sleep(300);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You can't access this program from that PC!\n";
        Sleep(200);
        exit(1);
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings, not pointer equality.

Comment: Or use `std::string` instead of `char[]` arrays.

Comment: As you’re using C++, you should use `std::string` instead of raw Character arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't have values that you can compare. They contain multiple values.

When you compare the two arrays, the arrays decay to pointers and you're comparing the pointers to see if they point to the same object. Of course, they don't.

If you want to compare each byte, you can use a function like `memcmp`. If you want to compare two strings, you can use a function like `strcmp`.

Comment: "Thing" is sufficiently ambiguous that arguably they do point to the same thing.  It would be clearer to say "They don't point to the same *place*" (the stored addresses are different).